# Add DataGrid DateTime columns dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to add `DateTime` (7/30/2011) columns dynamically in a `DataGrid`. I will upload a screenshot of my grid which I made manually. I want to make a range combobox. So if the user chooses 2 weeks, then the grid adds day by day columns.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Tip: make sure you use a Browser with a spelling checker. Set it to English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
private void AddColumns(GridView gv, string[] dateColumns)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dateColumns.Length; i++)
    {
        gv.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
        {
            Header = dateColumns[i],
            DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(String.Format("[{0}]", i))
        });
    }
}
```

This could be called on the Combobox `OnSelectionChanged()`

You can also use a DataTemplate to properly display columns:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DateTime}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={0:d}}"  />
</DataTemplate>
```

No just adjust your StringFormat for your needs:

Basic is `Binding="{Binding date, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"`

Comment: and how i can create datecolumns?

Comment: thanks for replay but it is very unclear for me :( where i must wright this? : Binding="{Binding date, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"

Comment: @Acid, you mention you were using WPF, DataTemplate enables you to do that, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx and it goes on your XAML.
But I'll suggest you to read the link, its short and provides a nice explanation. also on Channel9.msdn.com you'll find lot of screencasts. Good luck